# Drag and Drop. Limit the number of items you can wrap for a hot zone

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, drag-and-drop

In the code below, you need to limit the number of dropped objects per drop zone (`id='drop-zone1'`) to one. Now you can transfer as many objects as you want to this zone. So far I don’t understand how to do it, I implemented a simple Drag and Drop in Typescript (without libraries). React framework is used.

```
import React from 'react';//import

//component Main
export function Main() {

  //function that is triggered when moving over the allowed transfer zone
  function allowDrop(event: any){
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  //function triggered at the start of a move
  function drag(event: any){
    event.dataTransfer.setData('id', event.target.id);
  }

  //function that fires when dropped on a drop target
  function drop(event: any){
    let itemId = event.dataTransfer.getData('id');
    console.log(itemId);
    event.target.append(document.getElementById(itemId));
  }

   return (
     <div>

        <div className='drop-zone1' id='drop-zone1' onDragOver={allowDrop} onDrop={drop}></div>

        <div className='drag-zone1' id='drag-zone1' onDragOver={allowDrop} onDrop={drop}>
          <div className='pl1' id='pl1' draggable='true' onDragStart={drag}>Bearing</div>
          <div className='pl2' id='pl2' draggable='true' onDragStart={drag}>Shaft</div>
        </div>

     </div>
   );
}

export default Main;
```

I tried to limit the number of objects in the transfer zone through the `drop` function, but nothing happened.

Comment: What are you doing is fundamentally not allowed in react. In react you can *never* call things like "append" on a dom node in a situation like this. As soon as some other state changes, that will get wiped out instantly. It may appear to work now, but it will break the moment its used inside the context of a bigger application with other state. All DOM must be a pure function of the JSX and state with no imperative dom manipulation. Currently, it looks like you are trying to model drag and drop in react whilst using vanilla js constructs.